# Draw Table from Excel to Word Bookmark

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

A table is being inserted from Excel to Word.It populates the table by rows and columns. Vba opens my file in word .draw and fill the  table in my word document. The main issue i am having is that despite  i have inserted a bookmark in my word  document the table is not inserted  at the bookmark's place. My codes are as follows :-

```
Sub CreateTableInWord()

    Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, objTbl As Object, objRow As Object
    Dim objCol As Object, colSets As Long, numMonths As Long, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long
    Dim amt, dtStart, tblRows As Long, tblCols As Long, rw As Long, col As Long

    numMonths = Range("A1").Value
    amt = Range("B1").Value
    dtStart = Range("C1").Value
    colSets = Range("D1").Value 'how many sets of columns ?

    tblRows = 1 + Application.Ceiling(numMonths / colSets, 1) 'how many table rows?
    tblCols = colSets * 3                                     'how many table cols?

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    'Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
     Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\rakesh\Desktop\mailmerge\lease2.docx")

    Dim oRange As Object
    Set oRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("RS").Range

    Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range, _
                 NumRows:=tblRows, NumColumns:=tblCols)

    c = 0
    For n = 1 To colSets
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 1).Range.Text = "Instal No"
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 1).Range.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 2).Range.Text = "Amt(Rs)"
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 2).Range.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 3).Range.Text = "Due Date"
        objTbl.Cell(1, c + 3).Range.Bold = True
        c = c + 3
    Next n
    objTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1 ' wdAlignParagraphCenter

    rw = 2
    col = 0
    For i = 1 To numMonths

        'rw = 1 + Application.Ceiling(i / colSets, 1)  'fill across and then down
        rw = IIf(i Mod (tblRows - 1) = 1, 2, rw + 1)   'fill down then across

        objTbl.Cell(rw, col + 1).Range.Text = i
        objTbl.Cell(rw, col + 2).Range.Text = amt
        objTbl.Cell(rw, col + 3).Range.Text = Format(DateAdd("m", i - 1, dtStart), "dd/mm/yyyy")



        'col = IIf(i Mod colSets = 0, 0, col + 3)         'fill across and then down
        col = IIf(i Mod (tblRows - 1) = 0, col + 3, col) 'fill down and then across

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range...` you're not inserting the table at the bookmark...  You set `oRange` but then you don't use it.

Comment: I have change the oRange to  Set oRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("RS").Range. Getting Error :- The requested member of the collection does not exist

Comment: Would be useful to update your posted code to reflect any changes

Comment: ok i have removed the oRange and Set Orange , the  table is displayed in my word document but not at the bookmark.

Comment: Likely al lyou needed to do was change this - `Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=oRange, ...`

Comment: Thanks  for  your help. It works.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/table-from-excel-to-word-bookmark-vba.1133238. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«how to autofit the table column width i have tried objTbl.Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit i's not working»

Word is not Excel! Word has no such table property as EntireColumn. You really should spend some time learning Word's properties and methods. Try:

```
With objDoc
  Set objTbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Bookmarks("RS").Range, _
    NumRows:=tblRows, NumColumns:=tblCols, _
    DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
    AutofitBehaviour:=wdAutoFitContent)
End With
```

or:

```
objTbl.Columns.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `oRange` when adding the table:

```
Dim oRange As Object
Set oRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("RS").Range

Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=oRange , _
             NumRows:=tblRows, NumColumns:=tblCols)
```

Comment: Last but not the least  how to autofit the table column width i have tried  objTbl.Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit  i's not working

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need oRange, let alone use it when adding the table:

```
With objDoc
  Set objTbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Bookmarks("RS").Range, _
    NumRows:=tblRows, NumColumns:=tblCols)
End With
```