# Adding a HTML table to a bookmark in a Word document with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, html-table, ms-word, bookmarks

There are 2 parts to my macro.  1 part creates emails and 1 part creates a Word Document.  We use the Word feature when we don't have an email address.  This is an Excel macro using VBA.

The email macro creates a table (3 column) with the details, a blank row and then the total.  The # of rows depends on the number of records for the table.  The email table is created with HTML.  I'd like to use the same code (below) for the Word document and insert it at a bookmark (top of the 2nd page) in the Word document.  I'm not committed to HTML for this table.  I was trying to use code I had already developed instead of reinventing the wheel.

```
Do Until vStartRow > vEndRow
  DoEvents
  If Val(Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets("DNR List").Cells(vStartRow, 20)) <> 0 Then
    strRows = strRows & "<tr>"
    strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets("DNR List").Cells(vStartRow, 3) & "</td>"
    strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets("DNR List").Cells(vStartRow, 4) & "</td>"
    strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=right"">" & Format(Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets("DNR List").Cells(vStartRow, 20), "#,##0.00") & "</td>"
    strRows = strRows & "</tr>"
    MyBalance = MyBalance + Workbooks(DataBook).Worksheets("DNR List").Cells(vStartRow, 20)
  End If
                    
  vStartRow = vStartRow + 1
Loop
        
strRows = strRows & "<tr>"
strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows = strRows & "</tr>"
                
strRows = strRows & "<tr>"
strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & "Total" & "</td>"
strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=center"">" & " " & "</td>"
strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"" ""col align=right"">" & Format(MyBalance, "#,##0.00") & "</td>"

strRows = strRows & "</tr>"
strAfterRows = "</table></body>"
        
strAll = strBeforeRows & strRows & strAfterRows
            
StrBody3 = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & strAll
```

I use the following code to write the table to bookmark.  What I get is the code written to the bookmark instead of a table.  I'm sure the code I'm using is writing the string instead of the table.

```
WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookMarkName).Select
WrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkName
WrdApp.Selection.TypeText StrBody3
```

This is the first time, I've tried something like this.  Thanks for your help or suggestions in advance to write a table to a bookmark.....

Comment: You can use VBA to build a table in Word - eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640242/draw-table-from-excel-to-word-bookmark/61641834#61641834

Comment: Alternatively you can look these things up in the Object Explorer and online help.

Comment: @TimWilliams............Thanks........I'll take a look at that article and give it a try

Comment: @TimothyRylatt...........Thanks........I always try multiple things and search multiple times before posting on this site.  I have a 60 minute rule; where I try to figure things out on my own by reading and researching.  If I'm still spinning my wheels after 60 minutes, I'll post a question here.  I'm not looking for anyone to do this for me but rather kind of point me in the right direction; like you did earlier today.  That helped me solved that problem and I moved on to the final situation that needs to be fixed before I can roll out the macro.  Thanks for your help.........